# Saving 3 values on login form

Tags: html, authentication

I have a login form which requires 3 values, customer id, username and password. If I let the browser save the password, it only remembers the username and password, but not customer id, so it has to be written again each time.

I could just save the customer id in a cookie and read it from there, but that would be bad for those who don't want to save their credentials. Is there a way to handle this, for example detect if the user saved the credentials, and only then save the customer id to a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a remember me checkbox... if user wants he check or uncheck it. If checkbox is checked, store the values in cookie.
This will totally be on user's wish.

Hope this will help you out.